# Creating composite primarykey using a foreignkey and a non key attribute

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

This is my auto generated code after creating the batch table. while inserting data to this table

1. BatchID=1,Course_CourseID=1
2. BatchID=1,Course_CourseID=2

it is creating an error saying "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'BatchID_UNIQUE'".
I'm using C# 2010 express windows application as well as MySQl 5.1

My table schema is here

```
CREATE TABLE `batch` (
  `BatchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Course_CourseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NoOfStudents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClassRoom` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartDate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Day` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BatchID`,`Course_CourseID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BatchID_UNIQUE` (`BatchID`),
  KEY `fk_Batch_Course1` (`Course_CourseID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Batch_Course1` FOREIGN KEY (`Course_CourseID`)
  REFERENCES `course` (`CourseID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message quite clearly refers to this string:

```
UNIQUE KEY `BatchID_UNIQUE` (`BatchID`)
```

So what you have to do is either drop this index (with...

```
ALTER TABLE `batch` DROP INDEX `BatchID_UNIQUE`
```

... command, or just exclude this line from the table's definition (in `CREATE TABLE`).

All that said assuming that you really don't need your batch ids to be unique (in other words, there's no logical error in your `INSERT` statement. That seems to be the case, though: pair `BatchID-Course_CourseID` is already defined as unique (via PRIMARY KEY).

Comment: Good answer but she might have not understood it well.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. Drop your batch table and then run this sql. Rightly answered that you can not have two same vaues for a unique key. So I removed the unique key line as well.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `batch` (
  `BatchID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Course_CourseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NoOfStudents` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClassRoom` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartDate` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Day` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Time` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BatchID`,`Course_CourseID`),
  KEY `Course_CourseID` (`Course_CourseID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `batch` ADD CONSTRAINT `batch_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Course_CourseID`)
REFERENCES `course` (`CourseId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```